# Use siunitx to round numbers while using colortbl to color cells

Tags: tables, siunitx, colortbl, cellcolor

I typically use the `siunitx` package to round numbers in tables and use the `\cellcolor` command of the `colortbl` package to change the background colors of certain cells. However, as the following example shows, they do not really go together: Only numbers in non-colored cells are rounded correctly; numbers in colored cells are not rounded.

**How can I make `siunitx` to round numbers in the colored cells as well?**

[image: Table from example]

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\frame{
    \centering
    \sisetup{
        detect-mode,
        tight-spacing           = true,
        group-digits            = false,
        input-signs             = ,
        input-symbols           = ,
        input-open-uncertainty  = ,
        input-close-uncertainty = ,
        table-align-text-pre    = false,
        round-mode              = places,
        round-precision         = 3,
        table-space-text-pre    = (,
        table-space-text-post   = ),
    }
    \begin{tabular}{lSS}
        \toprule
        Cell background & {Number}                        & {Number in parentheses} \\
        \midrule
        With color      & \cellcolor{yellow!50}-.0399377* & \cellcolor{yellow!50}(.0358997) \\
        Without color   & -.030879**                      & (.0203602)                      \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to 'hide' the cell colour part from `siunitx`:

```
& {\cellcolor{yellow!50}} -.0399377* &
```

(The package can pick up simple `\color` commands but not at present `\cellcolor` ones.)